# Android - How to manipulate text before output to app?

Tags: android, text

I want to manipulate text between the input method and the output to the Application. I would ideally like to manipulate the txt via touch in the input box before sending it to the app. I am not talking about predictive systems our auto complete. I am looking to physically manipulate the text after it is typed in. Any ideas on how easy/difficult it would be to make this work?

Example, here is the normal flow:

Text Input IME --> Output Screen Aspect / Manager --> App or Communications System

I want to do the following:

Text Input IME --> Txt manipulation <--> Output Screen Aspect / Manager --> App or Communications System

Comment: what do you mean by manipulation? add/remove/replace/reorder chars? change of style?

Answer (score 0):

read on TextWatcher. you gain access to methods such as beforeTextChanged, onTextChanged, and afterTextChanged - go figure.